# retrofit & okhttpclient intercept 401 response

Tags: android, retrofit, okhttp

I'm trying to see whenever I get a response from my API with code 401.
But when I do, i get an IOException

```
@Override
public Response intercept(Chain chain) throws IOException {
    Request request = chain.request();
    Response response = chain.proceed(request);
    if (response.code() == 401) {
        mLoginToken.delete();
        Toast.makeText(mApplication.getApplicationContext(), R.string.session_error, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        Intent intent = new Intent(mApplication.getApplicationContext(), LoginActivity.class);
        intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
        mApplication.startActivity(intent);
    }
    return response;
}
```

I will get the error
java.io.IOException: unexpected end of stream on Connection{ proxy=DIRECT@ hostAddress= cipherSuite=none protocol=http/1.1} (recycle count=0)

At the line

```
        Response response = chain.proceed(request);
```

How should I get the responses with 401 (unauthorized code) in order to handle this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I usually use inteceptors for requests only, and to handle errors set an error handler on the rest adapter builder, see example below:

> Note: `cause.getResponse()` may return `null`

```
   yourRestAdapterBuilder.setErrorHandler(new ErrorHandler() {
                        @Override
                        public Throwable handleError(RetrofitError cause) {
                            switch (cause.getResponse().getStatus()) {
                                case 401:
                                    mLoginToken.delete();
                                    Toast.makeText(mApplication.getApplicationContext(), R.string.session_error, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                    Intent intent = new Intent(mApplication.getApplicationContext(), LoginActivity.class);
                                    intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
                                    mApplication.startActivity(intent);
                                default:
                                    // suppress or handle other errors
                                    break;
                            }
                        }
                    })
```

Comment: Is there any other default error handler, and If I set a new one, there will be some future problems?

Comment: If I am not mistaken the setting another error handler will just override the previously set error handler, and I am not sure how complex you want your error handling to be, you could always abstract the `case` code block into static functions to maintain readabillity in your code

Comment: Thank you for sharing this solution. I like it ;)

Comment: This doesn't explain why an IOException is thrown

Answer (score -1):

```
val contentType = response.body?.contentType()
        val charset: Charset = contentType?.charset(StandardCharsets.UTF_8) ?: StandardCharsets.UTF_8
        val message= response.body?.source()?.readString(charset)
```

It work for me and for good way